# MS Access Icon library

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am looking for a robust set of Icons which I would like to use in MS access. I would in particularly like Icons which are black and "simple"..  The main themes that my databases deal with are project management and financial analysis.
Any suggestions will be well appreciated on how to find or develop personalised icons.
Thanks,
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have these options:

1. You can try online icon editors like [X-Icon Editor](http://www.xiconeditor.com/).
2. Buy ready-made icons from web services like [IconArchive.com](http://www.iconarchive.com/tag/online-buy)
3. Create your icons in PhotoShop and convert them later online.